# How to make app from custom repository to show up in Boxee?

Tags: xml, boxee

I'm trying to add the [Hello World example](http://developer.boxee.tv/Examples%3a_The_Basics) to a custom repository on my server but the app won't show up in Boxee and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I can see the repository but not the app. Here is my configuration:

**server/repo/repository.xml**

```
<repository>
   <id>com.server</id>
   <url>server</url>
   <name>My repository</name>
   <thumb>thumb.png</thumb>
   <description>My Boxee app reposiory.</description>
</repository>
```

**server/repo/index.xml**

```
<apps>
   <app>
      <id>com.server.hello</id>
      <name>Hello World</name>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <description>Test application</description>
      <thumb>thumb.png</thumb>
      <repositoryid>com.server</repositoryid>
      <repository>server</repository>
      <media>video</media>
      <author>Me</author>
      <copyright>Me</copyright>
      <email>me@me.com</email>
      <type>skin</type>
      <startWindow>14000</startWindow>
      <platform>all</platform>
      <minversion>0.9.14</minversion>
   </app>
</apps>
```

The actual app is located in `server/repo/download` and named `com.server.hello-1.0.zip`

Answer (score 0):

yeah, this was an exciting moment for me too...
it all looks well for me (naming ids and same version numbers..), except the

```
 <url>server</url>
```

tag is missing in your repo/index.html. so the app doesn't know where to start. did that solve your problem?